# Send SMS leads to Generic Failure

Tags: android, sms

I am sending SMS through my application using a very common way that is explained in pretty much all tutorials. I use sendMultipartTextMessage with "sent Intents" and "delivery Intents", then a Broadcast receiver listen for the results and print things.

But, everytime I try to send a SMS, even with something like 10 characters, I always get a "Generic failure".

My default SMS app is working perfectly and I can send/receive SMS/MMS without any troubles so it can't be a network issue. I don't want my app to become my new default SMS app, I just want it to be able to send a short SMS sometimes. 
I tried a lot of things but everything has failed.

What is that issue and what can I do to get rid of it ?

Utils :

```
public static void sendSMS(Context context, String destination) {

    final String srcPhoneNumber = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(OptionsFragment.SMS_SRC_PHONE_NUMBER, null);
    final String message = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(OptionsFragment.SMS_MESSAGE, null);

    if (message == null || message.isEmpty() || destination == null || destination.isEmpty()) {
        Console.log('e', "tag", "sms sending failure");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("sms");
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", context.getString(R.string.empty_message));
        MyApplication.getInstance().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        return ;
    }

    final List<String> phoneNumbers = getPhoneNumbers();
    removeEmptyElement(phoneNumbers);

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.getInstance(), 0, new Intent("sms"), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.getInstance(), 0, new Intent("sms"), 0);

    for (String part : parts) {
        sentIntents.add(sentPI);
        deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
    }


    SmsManager.getDefault().sendMultipartTextMessage(destination, srcPhoneNumber, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
}
```

Receiver :

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String s = intent.getAction();
        if (s.equals("sms")) {

            String message = intent.getStringExtra("sms");
            if (message != null) {
                if (message.equals("OK")) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeFragment.this.getActivity());

                    builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.sms_send_success))
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setTitle("Success");

                    builder.create().show();
                } else {
                    Utils.makeErrorDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), message);
                }
            }
            else {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Utils.makeErrorDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),context.getString(R.string.send_error) + "Generic failure");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Utils.makeErrorDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),context.getString(R.string.send_error) + "No service");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Utils.makeErrorDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),context.getString(R.string.send_error) + "Null PDU");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Utils.makeErrorDialog(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(),context.getString(R.string.send_error) + "Radio off");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return;

                }

...
```

Comment: Does the `sendTextMessage()` method work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't

Comment: What type of class are you sending from? That is, is this in an Activity, a BroadcastReceiver, etc.?

Comment: I made a Utils class with a static method : public static void sendSMS(Context context, String destination). I call that method in a OnClickListenner i wrote for a button. The message is stored in the shared preferences

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant code.

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: What is `srcPhoneNumber`? I mean, whose number is that?

Comment: this is the user phone number, with 10 digits and no country code (as I'm testing it)

Comment: I believe that would be your problem. That method parameter is for the number of your service center, which is the part of your network that handles the middleman stuff for SMS routing and delivery. Unless your provider has given you a specific service center number to use, you should pass null for that.

Comment: Oh, it seems you are right. I don't know why i was sure that parameter was waiting the "From" number of the SMS. I'm so damn stupid ... Thank you very much you saved me a lot of time. Post it as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in the `SmsManager#sendMultipartTextMessage()` method (as well as the `sendTextMessage()` and `sendDataMessage()` methods) is for the number of your service center, not the sender's number. A service center is the part of your network that handles the storage, routing, and delivery of SMS messages, so passing an invalid number would result in the *generic failure* status you're getting. You simply need to pass `null` for this.