# SMS is not getting send

Tags: android, sms

My sms is not getting send , below is my code , i have used this code at 2 places, at one place it not going after "Sending message" toast and at other place it shows generic failure.Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

```
String phoneNo = "9712930869";
String message = "Hi!";
sendSMS(phoneNo, message);

 //---sends a SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    /*
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, test.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
    */

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Comment: If you are sending a lot sms together it will flood your phone so it is preferable to have some delay.

Next if you do delay you have to see to that it is not done in the UI thread or else you will get ANR.

Try using handlers, my friend suggested this, I tried and it works fine.

As for Generic issue, I am not sure.. The name Generic makes it sound like it could be a normal network error.

refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471155/send-sms-leads-to-generic-failure

Answer (score 0):

Use Sms permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```